# What is wrong with this theorem about closed and bounded non empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I am self-studying metric spaces from the book by Satish Shirali. One of the theorems from the chapter on "Topology of Metric Spaces" states:

**Let $F$ be a nonempty bounded closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $F$ is either
a closed interval or is obtained from some closed interval by removing a countable
family of pairwise disjoint open intervals whose endpoints belong to $F$.**

Now, let us consider the set $F = \{0\} \cup \left\{\frac{1}{n} ; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} = \left\{0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}, \cdots\right\}$. Clearly, F is both bounded as well closed.

But, it is neither a closed interval nor is it obtained from some closed interval by removing a countable family of pairwise disjoint open intervals whose endpoints belong to $F$.

If we consider
$F = \left\{0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4}, \cdots\right\} = [0,1] / S $, where  $S = (\frac{1}{2},1) \cup (\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}) \cup (\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3})\cup \cdots$, even then we shall have an **uncountable** family of pairwise disjoint open intervals.

This seems to contradict the given theorem. Where am I mistaken ? Any insight shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you say this is an **uncountable** family of intervals? This is indeed a countable family.

Comment: Sorry. Me being a stupid noob student, misunderstood 'countable' to be 'finite'. I know they are different. I just got terribly confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The family $$\mathcal H:=\left\{\left(\frac12,1\right); \left(\frac13,\frac12\right); \left(\frac13,\frac14\right);\cdots\right\}=\left\{\left(\frac1{n+2},\frac1{n+1}\right)\,:\, n\in\Bbb N\right\}$$ seems quite countable to me and $S=[0,1]\setminus\bigcup\mathcal H$, where $$\bigcup\mathcal H:=\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\, \exists I\in \mathcal H,\, x\in I\}=\left\{x\in\Bbb R\,:\, \exists n\in\Bbb N,\, x\in\left(\frac1{n+2},\frac1{n+1}\right)\right\}.$$

Now, the set $\bigcup \mathcal H$ itself may be uncountable (and in fact it kind of has to be, since it's an union of open intervals of $\Bbb R$), but the important fact is that there is a countable family of intervals the union of which is $\bigcup\mathcal H$, because here *countable* refers to the cardinality of one such $\mathcal H$ (if there is one).

Comment: Thanks. I got my error. Thanks a lot for clearing my stupid doubt.